# emission mix transparent not rendering properly

Tags: rendering

I have mix shader with emission node and transparent node

When I do render, there's no color & no emission

And eevee or cycle behaves the same

How is this happening ??

Here is the blend file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PKHJ9yLjjVtI_jf5BO1TdiYw1XbODigI/view?usp=sharing

thank you :)

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add screenshots of your setup, your material nodes and your results. What result are you expecting? This will make it easier for someone to understand your issue.

Comment: Please add more information. It is likely that you are dealing with a bug in blender that has been fixed in version 2.92. Please show images of the materials that you are using, images of the compositor nodes and the object in the viewport and the result you are getting. Also know that you should not use png for this kind of images. Update your question so that we can help you better.

Comment: thank you guys, I just edit the question

Comment: Don make the question depend on downloading a file. Use words to explain what you did and add images that show your settings and the results you are getting.